# check_prime.cpp (checks if input is a prime number)

Tags: c++, performance

**check_prime.cpp**

**Description**: Accepts user input to check if the user entered a prime number.

**Notes**: If any text inputted after an integer will be ignored.

**For example**: 1234.5678 and 98abc will be interpreted as 1234 and 98, respectively.

Please provide any feedback (positive or negative).

```
// check_prime.cpp
// Author: Chris Heath
// Date: 12/9/2018
// Description: Accepts user input to check if the user entered a prime number.
// Notes: If any text inputted after an integer will be ignored.
// For example: 1234.5678 and 98abc will be interpreted as 1234 and 98, respectively.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int is_prime (unsigned long int num)
{
    unsigned long int n;
    // avoid loop;  0 or 1 are never prime
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)
        return 0;
    // loop through numbers 0..(n/2)+1, trying to
    // divide one into the other with no remainder.
    for (n=2; n < (num/2)+1; n++)
    {
        // if we had no remainder during a revision,
        // input number has a divisor... NOT PRIME!
        if ((num % n) == 0)
          return 0;
    }
    // made it through gauntlet...prime!
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
 unsigned long int i;
 cout<<"Enter an integer to check if it is a prime: ";
 cin>>i;
 while(1)
 {
  if(cin.fail())
  {
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
   cout<<"You have entered wrong input.\nPlease try again: ";
   cin>>i;
  }
  if(!cin.fail())
  break;
 }
 if ( is_prime(i) )
  cout<<"\n"<<i<<" IS PRIME!"<<endl;
 else
  cout<<"\n"<<i<<" is NOT prime."<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only need to check up to `floor(sqrt(n))`. No matter how long your sqrt operation takes, it will eventually be faster to sqrt than to check all the extra numbers

Comment: can you rephrase (or expand) that comment so it more clearly (or explicitly) relates to my code? thanks

Comment: in the for loop in is_prime, you set the upper bound to. `n < (num/2) + 1`. You're checking too many numbers. instead, you want to only set the conditon to `n < floor(sqrt(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Formatting: Indent your code consistently. This makes it easier to understand and spot errors. Also, it attracts people here to read it at all. Your's is not a mess, but inconsistent still.
- Another rather obvious error is not to return a boolean for a function that gives you a true/false result. This is implicit documentation. If you return an int, you need to say what it means and how to interpret it, which the user of a function has to read and understand. With a boolean, that meaning is clear and requires no additional documentation.
- `using namespace std;` is okay-ish for an example like this. It's bad as regular habit and it's inacceptable when done in a header file. The problem this causes is the pollution of the global namespace. Replace this with single `using` statements, possibly restricted to a smaller scope like a class or function, or just prefix the `std::`.
- Your comment "loop through numbers 0..(n/2)+1" is misleading, your loop starts with value 2. Try to avoid repeating what the code does. Rather, use a comment (when necessary) to explain *why* you did something, in particular the `(n/2)+1` deserves some explanation.
- This leads to the point that the limit `(n/2)+1` is not optimal. Assuming there are two numbers `n` and `m` that divide a third value `k` that you're trying to find. If your approach is to try increasing values of `n`, then you can stop as soon as the resulting value of `k / n` is less than `n`. The reason is that `n` and `m` are interchangeable, so any possible result for `m` would have been tried as `n` already.
- The while loop could be structured differently, each operation is required only once, to remove redundancy. The first of these is `cin >> i`, the other is checking `cin.fail()`. Other than that the loop is fine and correct. As a strategy, think about how you would describe the steps to a human. Use this description as comments to form a template for your code. This then takes this form:

```
// output a prompt
cout<<"Enter an integer to check if it is a prime: ";
while (true)
{
    // try to read a single number
    cin >> i;
    // if reading succeeded, we're done
    if(!cin.fail())
        break;
    // skip remainder of the line of input
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    // output a warning and try again
    cout<<"You have entered wrong input.\nPlease try again: ";
}
```

- A stream can be used in a boolean expression to find out whether something failed or not. The above could have been simplified to `if (cin >> i) break;`.
- Just to mention it, when input failed, it sometimes makes sense to check for EOF as well. If you were reading numbers in an endless loop, sending an EOF (Control-D or Control-Z, depending on the terminal) can be used to exit that loop. If I send EOF to your program, it endlessly rotates prompting for a new value.
- The final `return 0` in `main()` is not necessary. This is a specialty of the `main()` function though, it doesn't apply to other functions.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5231607).

Since `is_prime` only has two possible return values, and given its name implies a binary result, it should return a `bool`, not an `int`.  Then replace the return statements with the proper bool values.

When checking for primes, you only need to go up to the square root of the number to check.  This value can be computed once then used in the loop condition, or you can check for `i * i <= num`, although this has the potential to overflow with sufficiently large `num`.

The check for 0 or 1 can be simplified to `if (num < 2)`.

Before the loop, you can check `num` to see if it is divisible by 2 and return an appropriate value.  Then you loop can start at 3 and increment by 2 (so you only need to check the odd numbers).

You should declare your variables as close to the place you first use them as possible, so your loop could be

```
for (unsigned long n = 3; ...
```

(or `for (auto n = 3UL;`).

When getting input, rather than `while (1)` with repeated conditions in the loop, you can say `while (!cin.fail())` and not check for that within the loop.

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback... all great points that i will incorporate asap

Comment: The last of your comments seems wrong. The loop is not to get multiple values but to retry when reading the (single) value failed. I made the same mistake on first read and to be honest, I blame that to some part on the indentation depth of a single space and the inconsistent use of indentation.

Comment: @uli If the original input succeeds, the first condition within the loop will be false, the second true, and the loop will be skipped.  If the original input fails, the first condition will be true, the input will be retried, and the loop stopped if the retried input succeeds.  Another way to look at it is since the `while(1)` loop ends in a conditional break, it can be changed to a `do`/`while` loop, and since the remainder of the loop body is a conditional that matches the end condition you can make it a `while(!cin.fail())`.

Comment: I'm still confused. In particular, I can't imagine repeating anything when the streamstate indicates success. Retry until failure doesn't make sense. We seem to agree on that the loop with redundant code can be improved though.

Answer (score 2):

- `int` is redundant in this variable declaration: `unsigned long int num`
  See the properties table on this reference page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types
- in this case, it is better to use `++n` rather than `n++` for better readability. `++n` precisely describes what this imperative procedure tries to do: increment the value of variable `n` by 1 and save the new value. The code is not relying on the extra step (make and return a copy of the original value) from post-increment operator to be functionally correct. Thus `n++` has a redundant step.

Comment: Could you explain why it is better to do these things?

Answer (score 1):

Even on a machine with relatively fast division, this algorithm (trial division) may be slower than a suitable sieve.  Even more so, once you improve the program to accept multiple inputs.

---

I encourage you to accept arguments rather than prompting for input.  That said, I still reviewed the input code in `main()`:

There's currently a bug that the program loops indefinitely asking for input when `std::cin` is closed.

The existing loop is structured poorly - instead of an infinite loop with a `break`, we should show the condition in the control part of the `while`:

```
std::cout<<"Enter an integer to check if it is a prime: ";
unsigned long int i;
while (!(cin >> i)) {
    if (cin.eof()) {
        std::cerr << "Input read failure\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE; // from <cstdlib>
    }

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    cin.clear();
    std::cout << "You have entered wrong input.\nPlease try again: ";
}
```

Look, no `break` or `continue` - that makes the code easier to read and understand.

---

There's an include that is unused, and can be safely removed:

> ```
> #include <string>
> ```

---

This comment is ambiguous:

> ```
> // Date: 12/9/2018
> ```

Avoid the abbreviated `d/m/y` form (because Americans swap the day and month around).  Prefer forms with non-numeric month name, or use ISO-8601 format (`yyyy-mm-dd`).